# Vue-Router How to make path property behave correctly?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am a React dev. And I cant figure out how Vue route works.

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import DashboardDefault from "./Dashboard/DashboardDefault";

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/dashboard",
      name: "dashboard",
      component: DashboardDefault
    }
  ]
});
```

In above code `DashboardDefault`is in proper folder. But when I navigate to /dashboard route, It does not work.

Comment: Did you check the console for errors? how are you navigating there?

Comment: @DerekPollard I am navigating by just typing. Anyway what might be the possible cause of this. If I am just using / as route that component gets rendered but not on /dashboard. Browser also has /# at end. Is that normal in vue?

Comment: the route would be `/#/dashboard` - and you didn't set history mode, so yes this would be normal: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: @DerekPollard My bad. I should have read the doc properly